# Why am I getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when reversing letters?

Tags: java, arrays, reverse, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.util.*;
class letters
{
    public static void main ()
    {
        char[] ar = new char[10]  ;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 10 letters");
        for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
        {
          ar[i] = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }
        for (int i=1; i>=0;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("the letters in reverse are"+ar[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my code but when I run it and enter the letters I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 at letters.main(letters.java:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing you error because your have done mistake in second loop where you initialize i with 1 (i = 1) and you run it for infinite loop (i>=0). Thats why it is showing you error Index out of bound. 
you should start your second loop with i = 9 and run it till (i>=0).

for (int i=9; i>=0;i++)

import java.util.*;
class letters
{
    public static void main ()
    {
        char[] ar = new char[10]  ;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 10 letters");
        for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
        {
          ar[i] = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }
        for (int i=9; i>=0;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("the letters in reverse are"+ar[i]);
        }
    }
}

Comment: ok sir i'll try it now

Comment: yes it worked! thanks!!

Comment: I think you meant `i--`. This would still not work

Comment: yes it would be i-- i did that only

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, there are errors in it, I believe what you want to do is to print out the reverse of the input string, which can be achieve with just a single loop like this;

```
public class HelloWorld
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     String name = "abcdefghij"; // your input
     for(int i=name.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
     {
       System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: no i specifically didn't want "abcdefghij" as the input, the input depends on the user so it has to be done in 2 loops only

Comment: Yes, I understand, try to understand the concept of char and string, a string is character array, which I expect you to understand, what you should do is to just substitute your character array in place of variable name in the sample code above.

Comment: but then sir what if i am making this program for a friend lets say and he enters some random letters which are not the ones which i had assigned in my program, then there would be an runtime error

Answer (score 0):

If u want to reverse a `String` input by the user,then it's better to use `StringBuilder` class to do so.

> This is how to do so.

```
String str=sc.nextLine();
String rev=new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
```